# Execute script once for a page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have added the following script to my asp.net master page

```
$(function() {

        $("#someDiv").someMethod(900, {
                chars: /\s/,
                doit: [" ( <a href='#' onclick='window.location.reload(true);' class='truncate_show'>more</a> . . . )", " ( . . . <a href='#' class='truncate_hide'>less</a> )"]
            });


        });
```

Now when the page loads first time, I see the link 'More'. On clicking 'More' a postback occurs and again the script gets fired. I want to stop executing the script once 'more' is clicked and the page gets reloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to set that up on the first load of the page, you might consider emitting it through `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` in `Page_Load`, within a `!IsPostBack` conditional.

Ultimately, it might be better if you could keep the show/hide functionality on the client-side completely.  It's always difficult drawing the lines between client and server.

If that's not helpful, update your question with a bit more code, and maybe I can give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing the default behavior of the link](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/triggerHandler#eventdata) to not actually occur so that you're just getting the `onclick` event and also maybe after you fire the event try unbinding it using `.die()`  (but you probably won't need that after you stop the link from going off)

Check out Events/die in the jQuery documentation.